# Regex c# pattern match

Tags: c#, regex

*Regex pattern(parent):*`([A-z]{1,})-([a-z]{1,})=` this pattern finds out(eg:mid-night).

*Regex pattern (child):* Need to Know regex pattern for finding words(midnight) and (mid night).

I need Regex pattern for finding those words.

Comment: When you'll find time to check the answers and probably accept an answer will be great ; )

Answer (score 0):

`[a-z]+ ?[a-z]+` matches both `midnight` and `mid night`.

Middle `" ?"` matches zero or one space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the parenthesis to regroup the words after.  I'm not sure what you're looking for with regard to including capitalization.
`([A-z]+)[ ]?([a-z]+)` will match `midnight`, `MIDNIGHt`, `mid night`, `Mid night`, `MID night`, etc.

If you're looking to match mid-night as well, use `([A-z]+)[- ]?([a-z]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your aim is but this regex should work:

```
([A-z]{1,})[ ]?([a-z]{1,})
```

Or try this one to match also your parent pattern:

```
([A-z]{1,})[ ]?-?([a-z]{1,})
```

But still I would' recommend to just split the **parent** match using **-**, so:

```
string parentMatch = "mid-night";
string[] words = parentMatch.Split('-');
```

Then you would get following output `words = { "mid", "night" }`, so you could either concatenate them or not